# Mikrotik Hotspot PHP API

Tags: php, api, mikrotik, hotspot

i'm working with php api by Mikrotik, but i do not how control if the user is disconnected do not run the limit-uptime?

this is my code

```
$API->write("/ip/hotspot/user/add", false);
$API->write("=name=".$usuario, false);
$API->write("=limit-uptime=".$segundos, false);
$API->write("=password=".$password, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version v6.34 of RouterOS you should use the following API command:

```
ip hotspot active login user="user" password="password" mac-address="AA:BB:CC:00:1122" ip="10.5.50.1"
```

You have to search in the ARP for the IP the device has assigned if you know its MAC address.

Also I strongly recommend to use the [PEAR2/Net/RouterOS](https://github.com/pear2/Net_RouterOS) library, is much more simple than the older you are using.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Keep-Alive" option in the user Hotspot configuration that controls this behavior.